# FormulaR1C1 issue with IF(AND)

Tags: vba

I have data in column C and I want to populate column B with the help of the formula `IF(AND)` using VBA. The line is below but I have "run time error 1004-Application-defined or object-defined error". Don't know where the problem is.

```
Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[1]>180),""180+Days"",IF(AND(RC[1]>90,RC[1]=180),""091-180 days"",IF(AND(RC[1]>60,RC[1]<=90),""061-090 days"",IF(AND(RC[1]>30,RC[1]<=60),""031-060 days"",IF(AND(RC[1]>=0,RC[1]<=30),""000-030 Days"")))))" 
Range("B2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B2:B" & Range("D" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of first ")" after 180

```
Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[1]>180,""180+Days"",IF(AND(RC[1]>90,RC[1]=180),""091-180 days"",IF(AND(RC[1]>60,RC[1]<=90),""061-090 days"",IF(AND(RC[1]>30,RC[1]<=60),""031-060 days"",IF(AND(RC[1]>=0,RC[1]<=30),""000-030 Days"")))))"
```

Comment: No worries.. :-)